# R data.table J behavior

Tags: r, data.table

I am still puzzled by the behavior of data.table J.

```
> DT = data.table(A=7:3,B=letters[5:1])
> DT
   A B
1: 7 e
2: 6 d
3: 5 c
4: 4 b
5: 3 a
> setkey(DT, A, B)

> DT[J(7,"e")]
   A B
1: 7 e

> DT[J(7,"f")]
   A B
1: 7 f  # <- there is no such line in DT
```

but there is no such line in DT. Why do we get this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data.table `J(7, 'f')` is literally a single-row `data.table` that you are joining your own `data.table` with. When you call `x[i]`, you are looking at each row in `i` and finding all matches for this in `x`. The default is to give `NA` for rows in `i` that don't match anything, which is easier seen by adding another column to `DT`:

```
DT <- data.table(A=7:3,B=letters[5:1],C=letters[1:5])
setkey(DT, A, B)
DT[J(7,"f")]
#    A B  C
# 1: 7 f NA
```

What you are seeing is the only row in `J` with no match to anything in `DT`. To prevent `data.table` from reporting non-matches, you can use `nomatch=0`

```
DT[J(7,"f"), nomatch=0]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: A,B,C
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps adding an additional column will shed some light on what is going on.

```
DT[, C:=paste0(A, B)]

DT[J(7,"e")]
###    A B  C
### 1: 7 e 7e

DT[J(7,"f")]
###    A B  C
### 1: 7 f NA
```

This is the same behavior as without `J`:

```
setkey(DT, B)

DT["a"]
###    B A  C
### 1: a 3 3a

DT["A"]
###    B  A  C
### 1: A NA NA
```

You can use the `nomatch` argument to change this behavior.

```
DT[J(7,"f"), nomatch=0L]
###  Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: A,B,C
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add an explanation of the `nomatch` argument and how it could be used?